# Replacing FORALL statement by typical SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have code in my procedure like this:

```
TYPE users_table IS TABLE OF tt_users.id%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE remove_users(user_ids users_table) IS
   --...
BEGIN
   --...
    FORALL i IN 1..user_ids.COUNT DELETE FROM tt_users WHERE id = user_ids(i);  
END;
```

Is any way to replace FORALL statement by typical SQL to improve performance?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  Prior to 12.1, you can't use associative arrays directly in a SQL statement.  In prior versions, you could convert the collection type to a nested table which you could use directly in SQL.  I wouldn't expect that to have a substantial impact on performance, however.

Comment: @JustinCave, Oracle 11.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on 11.1 or 11.2, you can't use an associative array in a SQL statement.  You could redefine your collection type as a nested table

```
CREATE TYPE users_tbl
    IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

If you do that, you can redefine your procedure to accept an instance of your new collection

```
PROCEDURE remove_users(user_ids users_tbl) IS
   --...
BEGIN
   --...
    DELETE FROM tt_users 
     WHERE id IN (SELECT column_value
                    FROM TABLE( user_ids ));  
END;
```

If you make those changes, however, it's unlikely that you're going to see a meaningful performance improvement.  In both cases, you're taking a collection in PL/SQL, passing it in bulk to the SQL engine, and letting the SQL engine delete multiple rows in a single call.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
delete from tt_users
    where id in (select id from user_ids);
```

Comment: Not if the table type is declared in the package? If it was declared at schema level then you could do that with `from table(user_ids)` but you can't use associative arrays directly in SQL (at least, until 12c, according to Justin's comment).

Answer (score 0):

If your users_table type is at the schema level (not in a package), you should be able to select from it:

```
 select id from table(user_ids);
```

And therefore delete from it as well:

```
delete from tt_users
where id in (select id from table(user_ids));
```

if non of this works, you may try to put your ids in a string and then use this string in a where clause:

```
 mystr := ',1,2,3,5,'

 delete from tt_users 
 where instr(mystr, ','||id ||',') > 0
```

But this one is limited to 4k.